# Spark 1.6: Exception when saving DataFrame into Hive

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I have a DataFrame loaded from a hive-table. After adding some data I want to write it back into hive, but get this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.5] failure: ``.'' expected but `:' found
```

Here´s some portion of my code:

```
var _resultsDF: DataFrame = _hiveContext.read.format("orc").load (_masterHDFS + "/apps/hive/warehouse/mytable");

def getValueList(): List[Any] = {
  List(
    "entry field1"
    "entry field2"
  )
}

def addRow(): Unit = {
  val rdd     = _sparkContext.parallelize (Seq (getValueList()))
  val rowRdd  = rdd.map (value => Row ((value: _*)))
  val rowDF   = _sqlContext.createDataFrame (rowRdd, _resultsDF.schema)

  // put DataFrame to results
  _resultsDF = _resultsDF.unionAll (rowDF)

  _resultsDF.write.format("orc").saveAsTable (_masterHDFS + "/apps/hive/warehouse/mytable")

  // => Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.5] failure: ``.'' expected but `:' found
}
```

Comment: I don't know exactly. But try by changing the name of the table you are writing and reading. Because the "mytable" named table is already exist what you have read before and again you are writing using the same name.

Comment: Did you try using `SaveMode.Append`, remove the union and save just the new `rowDF` records? `rowDF.write.format("orc").mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable(...)`. Did you verify that both schemas (mytable and "string") are identical?

Answer (score 0):

saveAsTable only seems to allow the table-identifier as parameter, therefore options have to be set for the base-uri. This worked for me:

```
var options: Map[String, String] = Map()
options += ("path" -> (_masterHDFS + "/apps/hive/warehouse/"))
_resultsDF.write.format("orc").mode(SaveMode.Append).options(options).saveAsTable("mytable")
```

or you just use save instead of saveAsTable

```
_resultsDF.write.format("orc").mode(SaveMode.Append).save(_masterHDFS + "/apps/hive/warehouse/mytable")
```